# Parameter 3 to mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expected to be a reference : php5.6 vs php7

Tags: php, mysql, php-7, php-5.6

It's simple code for inserting row. 
It works well by php 5.6, but by php 7.0.9 I get the error: "Parameter 3 to mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expected to be a reference".

```
function refValues($arr)
{
  if(strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0) //Reference is required for PHP 5.3+
  {
    $refs = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $value)
      $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
    return $refs;
  }
  return $arr;
}

...
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (player_id,ctime) VALUES(?,?)";
$types = "ii";
$args = array(10, time());

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $db_port, $db_sock);
if(!$conn)
  throw new Exception("Could not connect to mysql server");

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
if(!$stmt)
  throw new Exception("Could not prepare sql");

$res = call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', array_merge(array($stmt, $types), refValues($args)));
if(!$res)
  throw new Exception("Could not bind params");

if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
  throw new Exception("Could not execute stmt");
```

What does it wrong?

Comment: It requires a reference, so you cannot use the return value of array_merge, you need to provide actual variables for it to reference for arguments 3+.

Comment: From my testing, the refValues function you have should take care of the reference.  It works for me on 7.0.5.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is changing refValues function to

```
function refValues(&$arr)
```